# Understanding voltage sampling rate of induction motors

Tags: voltage, three-phase, induction-motor, waveform, rms

Why it is required to have a sampling rate of at least 4kHz when sampling the voltage waveform of a three phase induction motor?

I find most research papers use 4kHz but they don't state why.

I want to understand why 4kHz as appose to 5kHz or even 10kHz for example. I need this waveform to calculate the RMS.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Evidently, 4 KHz meets their needs. If you have different needs, by all means, use whatever sampling frequency you like.

Comment: And what if I use 4kHz to understand the needs? From my research, nobody seems to specify what the needs could possibly be for using 4kHz.

Comment: You haven't cited any specific papers, so there's no way I can comment on their needs. Similarly, you haven't specified what your own needs are, so I can't comment on that either!

Answer (score 0):

It is not required to sample the voltage of a three phase machine at 4kHz.  The rate voltage measurements should be taken is dependent on what is being measured, and how "good" of a measurement is needed.

Without seeing the papers I can make an educated guess as to why you are seeing a 4kHz measurement rate.

Cheap oscilloscopes can easily sample at rates 1000 times 4kHz so the measurement is most likely not from an oscilloscope.  4kHz is well within the range of most commercial VFDs PWM frequency.  So I will guess that the machines in those papers are being driven by VFDs and the voltage measurements are being taken from VFD itself.

A VFD will sync its voltage measurement to its PWM to ensure the measurement is done when the node being measured is no being driven by the VFD, which would skew the measurement.  Also note that many VFDs do not directly measure the voltage applied to the motor cable, but calculate the voltage from entered machine information and the supplied current.